# Coin toss problem. $F_{\alpha} = \{\omega: \frac{\#(k\le n: \omega_{\alpha(k)}=H)}{n}\to \frac{1}{2}\}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$\Omega=\{H,T\}^\mathbb{N}$,

so that a typical point $\omega$ of $\Omega$ is a sequence

$\omega=(\omega_1,\omega_2,\dots), \omega_n \in \{H,T\}.$

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the set of all maps $\alpha : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $\alpha(1)\lt \alpha(2)\lt \dots.$

For $\alpha \in \mathcal{A}$, let

$$F_{\alpha} = \left\{\omega: \frac{\#(k\le n: \omega_{\alpha(k)}=H)}{n}\to \frac{1}{2}\right\}$$

the 'truth set of the Strong Law for the subsequence $\alpha$'. Then, we have $P(F_\alpha)=1, \forall \alpha \in \mathcal{A}$.

Prove that $\bigcap_{\alpha \in \mathcal{A}}F_\alpha =\emptyset$.

I'm trying to prove this by showing that for any give $\omega$ we can find an $\alpha$ such that $\omega$ doesn't belong in $F_\alpha$, but I have been stuck here for a while. I would greatly appreciate any help on this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the sequence $\{H,T,H,T,H,T,\ldots\}$ that infinitely alternates between heads and tails. Clearly, the proportion of heads for this sequence converges to $1/2$. However, the subsequence made up of only the even terms, $\{T,T,T,\ldots\}$, does **not** have a convergent proportion of heads converging to $1/2$, despite there being other sequences with subsequences of even terms that do converge appropriately. This is an example of an $\omega\in\Omega$ that is contained in some $F_\alpha$ but not in others.

Every convergent sequence of interest can be reduced to the case $\{H,T,H,T,\ldots\}$ above by choosing an appropriate subsequence $\alpha$. So, every $\omega\in \Omega$ contained in some $F_\alpha$ will not be contained in all.

Comment: How can I argue that every convergent sequence of interest can be reduced to the case $\{H,T,H,T,\dots\}$ by choosing an appropriate subsequence? I don't understand how to show this part.

Comment: @takecare Take any suitably convergent sequence and create from it the subsequence that is: the first H, the first T after the first H, the first H after the last recorded T, the first T after the last recorded H, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

For each $\omega$ choose a symbol, either $T$ or $H$, that appears infinitely often in the sequence $\omega_1,\omega_2,\dots$. Now let $(\alpha(i))_{i\geq 1}$ consist of the indices of that symbol in $\omega$.

Comment: :-) Much nicer than mine +1

Comment: @ki3i Well, it is your idea, but simplified a bit.